# Mysql removes / from input file path string

Tags: java, sql

So I have this code that selects a file and copys its filepath

```
        File f= filechooser.getSelectedFile();
        path = String.valueOf(f.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(+path);
```

When I try run this it will show this:

```
        C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Desktop\Portfolio\1.png
```

But when it got store to the mysql db table it will be

```
        C:UsersusernameOneDriveDesktopPortfolio1.png
```

what should i do to regain the true value of the file path??

Comment: How do you store it in the mysql table?

Comment: INSERT INTO tbname (url) VALUES ('path'); @Alain-MichelChomnoueN url is set as VARCHAR(100);

Comment: ```PreparedStatement``` is what you need. It will deal with the necessary escapement.

Comment: i think thats not the problem I can add the string path to the database the only problem is that it removes "\" on the string

Comment: In that comment all you've done is repeat what your problem is. I have given you advice, which, even if it doesn't  work, will leave your code better than when it started